# Invisible Portion of Colorbox. (I would like it to be #FFF)

Tags: html, css, colorbox

I am working with this page.
http://www.careersinmusic.com/aaaa-testing-link.aspx

So when my main issue is the invisble area at the bottom. I would like it to be white, but I cant figure out how to modify the area.

Does anyone know where I can change this to white?

Thanks

PS. Also the scroll bar is an issue. The image I want to show is 986px tall.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

add `#cboxContent{background-color: white}` to your stylesheet